# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}

Tags: java, android, magento, soap

Below is my code.In this code I am using ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar. But I am getting the following error (all this code I put in `doInBackgroud()` method):

```
  SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER12);
            env.dotNet = false;
            env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
            env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "login");
            request.addProperty("username", "xxxx");
            request.addProperty("apiKey", "xxxxx");
            env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(null, env);
            Object result = env.getResponse();
            Log.d("AMAR sessionId", result.toString());
```

I got below error. I google it so many times and I got some suggestions. I tried almost all. But still I am not getting any solution. Please give me some Idea about Magento soap requesting.

```
  org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org  /soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}wsdl:definitions name='Magento' targetNamespace='urn:Magento'>@2:291 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4214c770)

at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2056)
at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:128)
at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:118)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:275)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
at org.embitel.screen.WishListActivity$WishListAsync.doInBackground(WishListActivity.java:68)
at org.embitel.screen.WishListActivity$WishListAsync.doInBackground(WishListActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?